# Marking facebook notificatios as read Graph API

Tags: vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

Hi Everybody,
             I am using
`https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/notifications?include_read=1&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`
to get notifications from facebook in my vb.net application but I cannot mark the notification as read I have tried `https://graph.facebook.com/NOTIF_ID?unread=false`but it does not seem to work.
Can anybody help me to mark the notification as read?
Please note in the code

```
USER_ID = xxxxxxxxxxxx
ACCESS_TOKEN = xxxxx.....xxxx(quite lengthy actually)
NOTIF_ID = notif_xxxxxxx_yyyyyyyy
```

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

The URL your are using for marking the notification read is completely correct. I am using it it for marking notification read in one of my applications. There must be some problem with the post request you are making.

Here is how i am marking the notification read (in C#/XAML). VB.NET implemention shouldn't be far from it.

I fetch the notificaiton data including read like you already do and saves them in a collection/List. Then to mark a single item read use the following code :

> string notif_id = item.Id; // My notification obj
>
> string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + notif_id + "?unread=false";
>
> FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
>
> IDictionary para = new Dictionary();
>
> dynamic result = await fb.PostTaskAsync(url, para);
>
> opResult = (bool)result; // If its true means notification has been successfully marked read

If you want to mark them in a single batch, then just use a `forearch` and above code inside it like :

`foreach(Notification item in NotificationsCollection)
{`

> // insert above code lines here

}

Hope this helps. :)